# checking if a string is in another string without pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring, c-strings

i've just started c programming and the task is to write a program to find a string in another string and if the target string was found print "Yes" and if it wasn't print "No". i've written a function to do the above task but it doesn't quite work. if anyone could tell me whats wrong with my code i'll be thankful.

```
void substring (char source[], char target[]){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int a = strlen(target);
    int b = strlen(source);
    while (source[i] != 0){
        while (target[j] != 0){
            if (target[j] == source[i])
                for (int k = 1; k < a; k++){
                    if (target[j + k] == source[i + k])
                        counter += 1;
                }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (counter == a)
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***write a program to find a string in another string and if the target string was found print "Yes" and if it wasn't print "No"***
For compactness, you could simply write it as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char source[4] = "test";
   char target[40] = "kkwkdnaxdtesttestkdkdtest";

   int n = 0;
   int found = 0;

   while(n < strlen(target)+1-strlen(source)){
      if (!strncmp(source,&target[n],strlen(source))) found++;
   n++;
   };

   if (found) printf("yes %d\n", found);
   else printf("no\n");

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
yes 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `strstr` in C, which does exactly your job.

Go through it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

## Sample Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char source[] = "This is a simple string";
    char Target[] = "simple";
    char *firstOccurrenceOfTarget = strstr(source, Target);

    if (firstOccurrenceOfTarget == NULL)
    {
        printf("No\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the task is to write a program without using pointers.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that, Anyway, Below answer can be used for that. And May I know the reason for that condition?

Comment: well i'm currently learning c online and its an assignment, haven't studied pointers yet.